# Debug web app on Android device while using USB tethering on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, usb, remote-debugging

I want to debug a web page on an Android device (see User Agent string below). I get a conflict between USB Tethering and using USB File Transfer.

The device is connected to my Ubuntu 16.04 development machine by USB, and USB tethering is set up on the device, so that my development machine is on the same network. In a Terminal window in Ubuntu, I use the following command to find the IP address of the Ubuntu machine:

```
$ ifconfig | grep "inet addr"
inet addr:192.168.42.xxx
```

I can then connect to `http://192.168.42.xxx/my_app/` from the Android device.

I then follow the steps at [Get Started with Remote Debugging Android Devices](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) in order to open a debug window. One of the steps that I need to apply is "Setting Android's USB mode to PTP". However, this creates a problem:

- When the USB mode is set to PTP, USB Tethering is automatically switched off
- If USB mode is not set to PTP, the remote device is not detected by Chrome Development Tools.

This means that I can debug a *pre-loaded* web page, but I cannot then *update* the page on the Android device, because it is no longer connected to the site on my development machine.

A workaround is to set up a Mobile Wi-Fi hotspot on the Android device, and connect my development machine to that. This leaves the USB connection free for the debugging process.

Is it not possible to use both USB Tethering and USB File Transfer (to allow debugging) at the same time?

**User Agent string**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.1; Moto G Play) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.105 Mobile Safari/537.36
```